# Как объединить пользователей с общим email?

Tags: java, алгоритм

Может кто- то подсказать, делаю задачу , где нужно объединить пользователей с общим имейл, с помощью двух hashmap, сделал одну, где ключ- имейл пользователя, а значение имя юзера, но там же значения перезатираются с общим ключом, что я делаю не так?

Имеется n пользователей, каждому из них соответствует список email-ов
(всего у всех пользователей m email-ов).
Например:

```
user1 ->xxx@ya.ru,foo@gmail.com,lol@mail.ru (xxx@ya.ru,foo@gmail.com,lol@mail.ru)
user2 ->foo@gmail.com,ups@pisem.net (foo@gmail.com,ups@pisem.net)
user3 ->xyz@pisem.net,vasya@pupkin.com (xyz@pisem.net,vasya@pupkin.com)
user4 ->ups@pisem.net,aaa@bbb.ru (ups@pisem.net,aaa@bbb.ru)
user5 ->xyz@pisem.net
```

Считается, что если у двух пользователей есть общий email, значит это
один и тот же пользователь. Требуется построить
и реализовать алгоритм, выполняющий слияние пользователей. На выходе
должен быть список пользователей с их email-ами (такой же как на
входе).

В качестве имени объединенного пользователя можно брать любое из
исходных имен. Список email-ов пользователя должен содержать только
уникальные email-ы. Параметры n и m произвольные, длина конкретного списка email-ов никак не ограничена.

Требуется, чтобы асимптотическое время работы полученного решения было
линейным, или близким к линейному.

Возможный ответ на задачу в указанном примере:

```
user1 ->xxx@ya.ru,foo@gmail.com,lol@mail.ru,ups@pisem.net,aaa@bbb.ru (xxx@ya.ru,foo@gmail.com,lol@mail.ru,ups@pisem.net,aaa@bbb.ru)
user3 ->xyz@pisem.net,vasya@pupkin.com (xyz@pisem.net,vasya@pupkin.com)
```

```java
public class Email implements Sort {
public void convert(List<User> source) {
     Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < source.size(); i++) {
            String[] list1 = source.get(i).getUser().split(":");
            String[] list2 = list1[1].split(",");
            for (int j = 0; j < list2.length; j++) {
                //ключ- имейл пользователя
                String key = list2[j];
                //значение - имя юзера
                String value = list1[0];
                map1.put(key, value);
            }
        }

        for (String key : map1.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(key + " " + map1.get(key));
        }
    }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
       Email email = new Email();
        List<User> source = Arrays.asList(
        new User("user1:xxx@ya.ru,foo@gmail.com,lol@mail.ru"),
        new User("user2:foo@gmail.com,ups@pisem.net"),
        new User("user3:xyz@pisem.net,vasya@pupkin.com"),
        new User("user4:ups@pisem.net,aaa@bbb.ru"),
        new User("user5:xyz@pisem.net")
        );
       email.convert(source);
    }
}
```

Comment: В чем проблема сделать `Map<String, List<String>>` ?

Comment: Это первой мапой сделать, где ключ- имейл, а значение имя юзера, где этот имейл повторяется? если да то как это реализовать не понимаю?

Answer (score 1):

1. Объявляем класс

   ```java
   class User {
     String name;
     Set<String> emails;
   }
   ```
2. Объявляем `Map<String, User> emails` (ключ - e-mail, значение - объект)
3. Объявляем `Map<User, User> dups` (ключ - пользователь, значение - основной пользователь)
4. Объявляем `Set<User> unique` множество уникальных пользователей
5. Пишем процедуру заполнения

   ```java
   void addUsers(List<User> userList) {
     for (User user : userList) {
       boolean isMainUser = true;  // Пока считаем, что пользователь основной
       for (String email : user.emails) {
         String prevUser = emails.putIfAbsent(email, user);
         if (prevUser != null) {  // Уже есть пользователь с таким e-mail
           // достаем основного пользователя
           prevUser = dups.getOrDefault(prevUser, prevUser);
           prevUser.addAll(user.emails); // добавляем основному пользователю свои адреса
           dups.put(user, prevUser);
           isMainUser = false;
         }
       }
       if (isMainUser)  // если все адреса были уникальными
         unique.add(user);
     }
   }
   ```
6. Теперь `unique` содержит уникальных пользователей с объединенными адресами

Comment: Выводит: user3 [xyz@pisem.net]
user1 [aaa@bbb.ru, ups@pisem.net], вместо user1 ->xxx@ya.ru,foo@gmail.com,lol@mail.ru,ups@pisem.net,aaa@bbb.ru (xxx@ya.ru,foo@gmail.com,lol@mail.ru,ups@pisem.net,aaa@bbb.ru)
user3 ->xyz@pisem.net,vasya@pupkin.com (xyz@pisem.net,vasya@pupkin.com)https://github.com/shaliginandrew/job4j_design/blob/a83d46714e776544d59459c44bda251f08202abe/chapter_001/src/main/java/ru/job4j/collection/Email.java

Comment: @АндрейШалыгин зачем вы переврали строку `prevUser.addAll(user.emails);`?

Answer (score 0):

небольшая опечатка в строке:

```
prevUser.addAll(user.emails); // добавляем основному пользователю свои адреса
```

поменять на:

```
prevUser.emails.addAll(user.emails);
```

и все будет работать.